# Diferencia entre <ion-item> y <div class="item"> ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Quisiera saber que diferencia existe entre usar uno frente al otro, debido que uno lo veo en la documentación de estilos (***css***), y el otro en la de ***javascript***.

1. Que ventajas tiene uno frente al otro al crear los templates

```html
<!--Opcion 1-->

<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      ...
    </li>
</ul>


<!--Opcion 2-->

<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
    Hello, {{item}}!
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

2. Ventajas entre crear los templates usando ***index.html*** o ***type="text/ng-template"***

```html
<!-- Opcion 1 - index.html -->

<div class="list">
  <p></p>
  <h1></h1>
</div>


<!-- Opcion 2 -->

<script type="text/ng-template" id="todos.html">
    <!-- Contenido plantilla -->     
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**>>1.Que ventajas tiene uno frente al otro al crear los templates**

La diferencia fundamental es que al usar `<ion-list>` y `<ion-item>` empleas la directiva por lo que tienes mas funcionalidad y acceso a mas opciones sobre la api que esta implementa.

Lo recomendable es usar las directivas.

En los foros de `ionic` se planteo el mismo tema

[Ion vs div directives](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-vs-div-directives/7524)

[Difference between  and `<ul class=“list”>`?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/difference-between-ion-list-and-ul-class-list/30884)

**>>2.Ventajas entre crear los templates usando index.html o type="text/ng-template"**

No veo que exista una ventaja en un metodo u otro, quizas dependa como  defines el template.

Si usas un `index.html` solo podras definir un template por archivo, en cambio al usar el `type="text/ng-template` puedes definir varios en un mismo fichero `.js`

Comment: Mas que claro, gracias

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación oficial en la siguiente liga:

- [ion-list - Directive in module ionic -  Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/)

#### Español:

> Cómo sea, usando las directivas ionList e ionItem hace más fácil soportar varios modos de interacción, como arrastrar para editar (swipe), arrastrar y reordenar (drag), y remover elementos.

#### Inglés:

> However, using the ionList and ionItem directives make it easy to support various interaction modes such as swipe to edit, drag to reorder, and removing items.

Por lo tanto depende que quieras crear, pero si tu lista depende de algunas interacciones ya mencionadas en la cita traducida, te recomiendo utilizar las directivas de Ionic.